# It seems that array sorting method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, sorting

Array.sort() function isn't returning expected result. Is that how it actualy works, or what?

```
const arr = [1, 5, 12, 8, 17];
console.log(arr.sort());
```

Expected result would be: [1, 5, 8, 12, 17]
but result I get is: [1, 12, 17, 5, 8]

Comment: The default comparison function for `.sort()` compares values as *strings*. You have to pass an explicit comparator function if you want to do anything else.

Comment: Try `arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)`.

Comment: @slider that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to sort array of integers. If you don't pass a callback by default it will sort according to UTF-16 code value units. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. The default sort order is built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values

```js
const arr = [1, 5, 12, 8, 17];
console.log(arr.sort((a,b) => a - b));
```